# Variable Interpolation in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am having trouble in variable interpolation in terraform. Here is what my terraform configuration looks like. i.e variable inside builtin function

```
variable "key" {}

    ssh_keys {
        path     = "/home/${var.provider["user"]}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = "${file(${var.key})}" 
    }
```

Command: **terraform apply -var 'key=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'**

It's not reading the value of "key" from command line argument or from env variable. However when i hardcore the value in .tf file, it works. Like below.

```
key_data = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}"
```

Comment: Are you overriding the command line and/or env input of the variable by hardcoding it to be empty in the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `${ ... }` syntax is only used when embedding an expression into a quoted string. In this case, where your `var.key` variable is just being passed as an argument to a function already within a `${ ... }` sequence, you can just reference the variable name directly like this:

```
key_data = "${file(var.key)}"
```

Nested `${ ... }` sequences are sometimes used to pass an interpolated string to a function. In that case there would first be a nested set of quotes to return to string context. For example:

```
key_data = "${file("${path.module}/${var.key_filename}")}"
```

In this more complicated case, the innermost string expression is first evaluated to join together the two variables with a `/`, then that whole string is passed to the `file` function, with the result finally returned as the value of `key_data`.

Comment: I've tried to use @martin-atkins answer here along with a count but have run into difficulty. Have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942962/terraform-nested-interpolation-with-count in case anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you were using the wrong flag for the scenario you described above.

If you want to specify a path to a file use the "-var-file" flag as follow:

```
 terraform apply -var-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you must use the "-var" flag then you must specify the content of the file as follow:

```
terraform apply -var 'key=contenctOFPublicKey'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, further both the given example usages of -var-file and -var are also wrong. -var-file is used to provide alternate file containing variable values (instead of terraform.tfvars). -var is used to pass a value to the variable (correctly mentioned above) but it will not work with the given code in question.

Answer (score 0):

ssh_keys - (Optional) Specifies a collection of path and key_data to be placed on the virtual machine.

```
Note: Please note that the only allowed path is /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys due to a limitation of Azure.
```

refer: [AZURERM_VIRTUAL_MACHINE](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html)